# how to render a list of row/column/value to a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, algorithm

I have a demo here that basically explains my needs.

http://jsfiddle.net/ailerifren/3v8hf/

```
var dataClass = function (_x, _y, _v) {
    this.x = _x;
    this.y = _y;
    this.v = _v;
}

var dataList = [
new dataClass('x1', 'y1', 10),
new dataClass('x1', 'y2', 11),
new dataClass('x2', 'y1', 12),
new dataClass('x2', 'y2', 13),
new dataClass('x2', 'y3', 14),
new dataClass('x3', 'y2', 15)];

$(function () {
    var rows = [];
    var columns = [];
    $.each(dataList, function (i, v) {
        if ($.inArray(v.x, rows) < 0) rows.push(v.x);
        if ($.inArray(v.y, columns) < 0) columns.push(v.y);
    });

    var htmlString = '<tr><th></th>';
    $.each(columns, function (i, v) {
        htmlString += '<th>' + v + '</th>';
    });
    htmlString += '</tr>';

    $('#matrix').append(htmlString);

    htmlString = '';
    $.each(rows, function (ri, rv) {
        htmlString += '<tr><td>' + rv + '</td>';
        $.each(columns, function (ci, cv) {
            var val;
            $.each(dataList, function (i, v) {
                if (v.x == rv && v.y == cv) val = v;
            });
            htmlString += '<td>' + (val ? val.v : '') + '</td>';
        });
        htmlString += '</tr>';
    });
    $('#matrix').append(htmlString);

});
```

I have this list with row names and column names and their corresponding values. Is there an elegant way to render them into an html table?

I know I could use templates, but that's not really my point. My main problem is I couldn't figure out an efficient way to formulate the list to a table like format.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Not sure if you care to, but have you checked out jQuery Datatable plugin? Excellent plugin for dumping an object into and getting a full featured table (with option like search and paging). http://www.datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a cleaner representation of your data:

```
var dataTable = [
    [10,11,''],
    [12,13,14],
    ['',15,'']
];
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/hBhr6/)

Comment: my question is actually how to manipulate my list into a table like your dataTable

Comment: You mean convert your `dataList` (array of dataClass objects) into a `dataTable` (array of arrays)?